# How to draw 2 figures that slices the sphere in 2 different ways?

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf, tikz-cd, tikz-3dplot, tikz-3d

Here is the figure I wanna draw in overleaf:

> [image]

Any advice about how to draw this, please?

Comment: You could read the PGF and tikz-3dplot manuals.  You could search for related images on the internet and steal them.

Comment: Can you please provide a link for those manuals?@JohnKormylo

Comment: @Happy: If you have a LaTeX installation on your computer, you already have the manuals. Mac/linux: "texdoc tikz-3dplot", Windows: ?. -or use this link: https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=tikz-3dplot

Comment: Others possibilities are using [sketch](http://sketch4latex.sourceforge.net/) or [Asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/). For Sketch there is even an [exporter for Blender 2.5](https://blenderartists.org/t/sketch-exporter-for-blender-a-tool-for-latex-users/400137)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a 2d solution based on clips and scopes (a lot of clips and scopes). It also uses the tikz library `intersetctions` to obtain some points. I made a couple of macros, the first one is called `\spherepoints` and puts a few coordinates around a sphere that are necessary for the clips. These coordinates are defined with respect to the intersection points between curves. Here they are:
[image]

Then I made other macros to draw the ellipses: complete, visible part (clip) or hidden part (clip again). With all that in mind, this is the (not very short) code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\def\sr{2} % sphere radius

% some points in the sphere
\newcommand{\spherepoints}
{%
  \foreach[count=\xi]\i in {-1,1}
  {%
    \cellipse{0.25*\i*\sr}{draw=none,name path global=A-\xi}
  }
  \begin{scope}[rotate=120]
    \cellipse{0}{draw=none,name path global=A-3}
  \end{scope}
  \path [name intersections={of=A-1 and A-3,name=B}];
  \path [name intersections={of=A-2 and A-3,name=C}];
  \coordinate (P1) at (-\sr-0.1, \sr+0.1);
  \coordinate (P2) at (-\sr-0.1, 0.375*\sr);
  \coordinate (P3) at (-\sr-0.1, 0);
  \coordinate (P4) at (-\sr-0.1,-0.375*\sr);
  \coordinate (P5) at (-\sr-0.1,-\sr-0.1);
  \coordinate (Q1) at ( \sr+0.1, \sr+0.1);
  \coordinate (Q2) at ( \sr+0.1, 0.375*\sr);
  \coordinate (Q3) at ( \sr+0.1, 0);
  \coordinate (Q4) at ( \sr+0.1,-0.375*\sr);
  \coordinate (Q5) at ( \sr+0.1,-\sr-0.1);
  \coordinate (S1) at (intersection of  C-2--C-4 and Q1--Q5);
  \coordinate (R1) at (intersection of  C-2--C-4 and P1--P5);
  \coordinate (S2) at (intersection of  B-2--B-4 and Q1--Q5);
  \coordinate (R2) at (intersection of  B-2--B-4 and P1--P5);
}

% complete ellipse
\newcommand{\cellipse}[2]% height, style
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\a{sqrt(\sr*\sr-1.5*#1*#1)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\b{\a/sqrt(3)}
  \draw[#2] (0,#1) ellipse (\a cm and \b cm);
}

% ellipse, hidden part
\newcommand{\hellipse}[2]% height, style
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\a{sqrt(\sr*\sr-1.5*#1*#1)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\b{\a/sqrt(3)}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (-\sr-0.1,1.5*#1) rectangle (\sr+0.1,\sr+0.1);
    \draw[#2] (0,#1) ellipse (\a cm and \b cm);
  \end{scope}
}

% ellipse, visible part
\newcommand{\vellipse}[2]% height, style
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\a{sqrt(\sr*\sr-1.5*#1*#1)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\b{\a/sqrt(3)}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (-\sr-0.1,1.5*#1) rectangle (\sr+0.1,-\sr-0.1);
    \draw[#2] (0,#1) ellipse (\a cm and \b cm);
  \end{scope}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
% top left sphere
\begin{scope}
  \vellipse{0}{blue}
  \hellipse{0}{blue!25}
  \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (\sr);
\end{scope}
% arrow
\draw[magenta,thick,-latex] (1.3*\sr,0) -- (1.7*\sr,0);
% top right sphere, bottom half
\begin{scope}[shift={(3.5*\sr,-0.5*\sr)}]
  \cellipse{0}{thick}
  \draw[thick] (\sr,0) arc (0:-180:\sr);
\end{scope}
% top right sphere, top half
\begin{scope}[shift={(3.5*\sr,0.5*\sr)}]
  \cellipse{0}{draw=none,fill=white,fill opacity=0.75}
  \vellipse{0}{thick}
  \hellipse{0}{blue!25}
  \draw[thick] (\sr,0) arc (0:180:\sr);
\end{scope}
% bottom left sphere
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,-4*\sr)}]
  \spherepoints
  \foreach[count=\xi]\i in {-1,1}
  {%
    \vellipse{0.25*\i*\sr}{blue,name path global=A-\xi}
    \hellipse{0.25*\i*\sr}{blue!25}
  }
  \begin{scope}[rotate=120]
    \clip (R1) -- (S1) -- (S2) -- (R2) -- cycle;
    \vellipse{0}{blue}
    \hellipse{0}{blue!25}
  \end{scope}
  \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (\sr);
\end{scope}
% arrow
\draw[magenta,thick,-latex] (1.3*\sr,-4*\sr) -- (1.7*\sr,-4*\sr);
% bottom right sphere, bottom part
\begin{scope}[shift={(3.5*\sr,-5*\sr)}]
  \cellipse{-0.25*\sr}{thick}
  \clip (-\sr-0.1,-0.375*\sr) rectangle (\sr+0.1,-\sr-0.1);
  \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (\sr);
\end{scope}
% bottom right sphere, middle left part
\begin{scope}[shift={(3*\sr,-4*\sr)}]
  \spherepoints
  \cellipse{-0.25*\sr}{draw=none,fill=white,fill opacity=0.75}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (R1) -- (S1) |- (P5) -- cycle;
    \cellipse{0.25*\sr}{thick}
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (R2) |- (0,0) |- (P4) |- (Q5) -- (S2) -- cycle;
    \cellipse{-0.25*\sr}{thick}
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (P4) rectangle (0,0);
    \hellipse{-0.25*\sr}{blue!25}
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[rotate=120]
    \clip (R1) -- (S1) -- (S2) -- (R2) -- cycle;
    \cellipse{0}{thick}
  \end{scope}
  \clip (P2) -| (0,0)  |- (P4) -- cycle;
  \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (\sr);
\end{scope}
% bottom right sphere, middle right part
\begin{scope}[shift={(4*\sr,-4*\sr)}]
  \spherepoints
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (R1) -- (S1) |- (P1) -- cycle;
    \cellipse{0.25*\sr}{thick}
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (S2) -- (R2) |- (Q1) |- (0,0) |- (Q4) -- cycle;
    \cellipse{-0.25*\sr}{thick}
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (Q4) rectangle (0,0);
    \hellipse{-0.25*\sr}{blue!25}
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[rotate=120]
    \clip (R1) -- (S1) -- (S2) -- (R2) -- cycle;
    \cellipse{0}{thick}
  \end{scope}
  \clip (Q2) -| (0,0)  |- (Q4) -- cycle;
  \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (\sr);
\end{scope}
% bottom right sphere, top part
\begin{scope}[shift={(3.5*\sr,-3*\sr)}]
  \spherepoints
  \vellipse{0.25*\sr}{thick,fill=white,fill opacity=0.75}
  \hellipse{0.25*\sr}{blue!25}
  \clip (P2) rectangle (Q1);
  \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (\sr);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Can I use `documentclass{book}` instead? as I know that(correct me if I am wrong please) any document can not have more than 1 document class and I am already using the document class book.

Comment: @Happy, yes you can use book, article, beamer, etc. Just copy-paste the `tikzpicture` in your document and `\usepackage{tikz}` `\usetikzlibrary{intersections}` in the preamble.

Comment: what do you mean by copy-paste `tikzpicture` in my document? do you mean copying the code you gave me above? or taking a screen shot of your photo?

Comment: @Happy, I mean the code, of course. Or you can compile the file as `standalone` and the include the pdf in your document with `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Oh, that is a new method, I did not know that method before, thank you very much!